# Tablet Monitor + Touchscreen connected to raspberry pi

Tags: touchscreen

I got a used tablet, that doesnt function anymore (battery died) and I wanted to use the LCD display and touchscreen to connect to the raspberry pi.
The LCD model is (DX7005 CYX) and touchscreen (h-ctp070-011), I'm trying to find something one the internet, but not lucky yet, if someone knows how to connect this 2 into the raspberry pi, I'll be very happy and thankfull xD

Comment: if only battery is the problem- power it from USB, install VNC server on RPi and VNC client on the tablet

Comment: I can't turn that on. But the display and touch is trully working

Comment: What do you mean > I can't turn that on. But the display and touch is trully working –
> Caio Keto ?? Did you get this working? Or do you mean that the Display & Touchscreenwork in general? If you did get this working, could you please share how you did it, it would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What tablet model is that? Usually you get a replacement battery for a reasonable price, instructions how to exchange it are found on the web.